# Is there a word meaning the opposite of clever and witty but not stupid?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know a bunch of people who are very smart and good at school, but somewhat lacking in the wit department. I'm looking for a way to describe them that doesn't end up meaning that they're stupid. Thank you!

Comment: Book-smart  (in contrast to street-smart)?

Comment: Note that finding the opposite of a word depends on what you are trying to invert. E.g. The opposite of "man" depends on what you're focusing on. Gender => Woman. Age => Boy. Cognitive capacities => Animal. Morals/ethics => Monster. Biological nature => Machine.

Comment: Difficult to see how something which is the opposite of 'clever' is going to be applied to people who are 'very smart'. Could you perhaps define your terms a little more? If you explain or give examples for the kind of 'wit' you are thinking of it would probably help.

Comment: .........nerdy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***Pedestrian***

Defined in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/139574?redirectedFrom=pedestrian#eid) (subscription required)

> Of writing: prosaic, dull; uninspired, undistinguished. Also, of people and things: commonplace, ordinary.

The OED gives an example from 1938:

> P. Kavanagh *Green Fool*   'Without the little touches of roguery a cobbler is only a plain *pedestrian* thinker who can never scale the heights where fairies of every craft dwell.'

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking *dull*.

Comment: @Clare I was ever given to sesquipedality.

Answer (score 0):

There are those with no learned skills at all whose only skill is to appear witty. People who have not learned how or do not spend their time working at appearing witty can be called: Uncomplicated, Redoubtable, Vital, Genuine, Sincere.

Comment: "There are those with no learned skills at all whose only skill is to appear witty." That is the exact opposite of what the OP is asking about. He's looking for a word to describe people who are **intelligent but not witty**. Your suggestions also make no sense.

Comment: You are mistaken. What you are correcting is an initial comment on how intelligent witty people may or may not be.

The answer is the short list of words and stands with or without the comment on witticism.

Answer (score -7):

So you're referring to those only good with academic intelligence and not street smarts/ applying their wit in real life occasions. If that's the case, then here are some words:

dull-witted  dull  naive  slow  simple-minded  ignorant gullible  dense  obtuse  naive  unimaginative

Comment: Half of these words are not suited to someone who is not stupid.